# Loading multiple textures in an array in Android Andengine

Tags: android, arrays, textures, loading, andengine

I'm using a for loop to implement the loading and handling of Sprite objects for display for a keyboard for a game of hangman. The loop makes it through to the 4th iteration and crashes. The error it gives me says:

```
Texture must not exceed the bounds of the atlas
```

This should actually work as all the images are 64x64 and the atlas is declared as such:

```
this.mAtlas[i] = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),256, 256,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
```

I'm using an array of atlases and an array of textures in which to load the images and the I load the atlas. After that I'm then passing the texture into a custom class that implements sprite. And finally I attach the loaded sprite into the scene. Here is the whole code for the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
{
    String name = Integer.toString(i);
    name+= ".png";
    this.mAtlas[i] = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),256, 256,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mTexture[i] = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAtlas[i], this, name, (i*64) + 5,0);
    this.mAtlas[i].load();
    if(i % 13 == 0)
    {               
        yPos -= 64;
    }
    if(i < 26)
    {
        letterPass = alphabet.substring(i);
    }
    else if(i == 26)
    {
        letterPass = "BackSpace";
    }
    else if(i == 27)
    {
        letterPass = "return";
    }
    letters[i] = new Letter((i * 64)+ 5.0f, yPos, this.mTexture[i].getHeight(), this.mTexture[i].getHeight(), this.mTexture[i], this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    letters[i].setLetter(letterPass);
    mScene.attachChild(letters[i]);     
}
```

The line where the crash occurs is:

```
this.mTexture[i] = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAtlas[i], this, name, (i*64) + 5,0);
```

I cannot seem to figure out why it's crashing and I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You texture atlas is 256x256 pixels large. Your sprites are 64x64 pixels and you create an atlas for each of them... That means you are wasting a lot of space. And it doesn't even work because on this line:

```
    this.mTexture[i] = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAtlas[i], this, name, (i*64) + 5,0);
```

You are placing the texture onto atlas at position `[i * 64 + 5, 0]`. I bet it fails on 4th texture. `3 * 64 + 5 +64 = 261`, you are out of bounds.